# PHP sending foreigner euro sign from jQuery to php not formated ( in json )

Tags: php, javascript

I have foreigner euro sign that is in the client side. I take this parameter and convert it to json, then I send in post via json to a PHP back-end.

The problem is that in the server side the character got corrupted

```
campaignsJson.campaigns[i] ={}; 
campaignsJson.campaigns[i].advertiser_id = advertiserId;
campaignsJson.campaigns[i].sign_id = sign_id;
var campaignsJsonstringify = JSON.stringify(campaignsJson);
alert(campaignsJsonstringify); // THE eruo sign is ok 

//send via form
$.sendPost = function() {
    var campaignsJsonstringify = JSON.stringify(campaignsJson);
    $('#campaigns_json').val(campaignsJsonstringify);
     document.getElementById("container_send").submit();
}

<form id="container_send"  action="campaigns_action.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="campaigns_json" name="campaigns_j" value=""/>          
</form>


//PHP
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
     $isError = false;
     if($_POST['campaigns_j'])
     {
        $campaigns_json = $_POST['campaigns_j'];
        echo $campaigns_json;
        //Here is the foreigner euro sign is printed as gibrish
     } 
}
```

I need the string that is valid string and foreword it to third party API
for this I need to keep the string that is sent from the client valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: the posted data will be encoded with UTF-8 as default if you don't specify any. so you should use function [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in your php code like this: `$campaigns_json = utf8_decode($_POST['campaigns_j']);`

Comment: @shawnzhu "You should use `utf8_decode`" ...if you want it to be in Latin-1 instead. 9 out of 10 times I'd advise against that and suggest the OP learn about encodings and how to handle them properly instead.